# create a single dimension array from multidimensional array key

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array,

```
Array 
 (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 53
            [Lft] => 11
            [Rght] => 24
            [Title] => cafeteria
            [Description] => Cafeteria
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 55
            [Lft] => 20
            [Rght] => 21
            [Title] => sanitary
            [Description] => Sanitary
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 58
            [Lft] => 22
            [Rght] => 23
            [Title] => medic
            [Description] => Medic
        )

 )
```

How do I get an array of all the ids easily, without having to loop through each the traditional way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to extract a single dimensional array from the multidimensional array based on a `key`.

```
$roles = array_column($roles, 'ID');
```

Returns

```
Array (
    [0] => 53
    [1] => 55
    [2] => 58
)
```

Comment: self answers area great, but not when its clearly a duplicate.